# Javascript - set date 10 days in the future in this format dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. 21/08/2010)

Tags: javascript

i would really appreciate some help creating some java script that will eventually be used in Selenium that automatically sets a date 10 days ahead from the current date and displays in the following format dd/mm/yyyy.

i currently have the script below but i'm not getting anywhere with it. The parts in **BOLD** are what i suspect to be creating the issue.

var myDate=new Date(); myDate.**now.format**(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+5),(**"dd/mm/yyyy"**);

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Jules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572561/javascript-set-date-10-days-in-the-future-in-this-format-dd-mm-yyyy-e-g-21-08

you already have the same question dont know y you asked this multiple time ..........

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't support formats. There is some libraries that have the functionality. But here is what you can do:

```
var MyDate = new Date(),
    MyDateString;
MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate() + 10)
MyDateString = MyDate.getDate() + '/' + MyDate.getMonth() + '/' + MyDate.getFullYear()
alert(MyDateString)
```

..fredrik

Answer (score 0):

Check the following links will help you to achieve the functionality you want

[A simple formatDate function for JavaScript](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/282495.aspx)

[JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("m/dd/yy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library. Its awesome date library that should be part of a web development toolkit!