# How to set X number of days in the future using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add number of days to today’s date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

I need to get tomorrow and X number of days into the future using JavaScript and print in the format MM-DD-YYYY. For example, if I wanted to pass in the following parameters, I would like the start day to be tomorrow of the current date and the end date to be 31 days from now.

```
startDate: '02-02-2013',
endDate: '03-04-2013',
```

How can this be done?

Comment: How to get a date relative to today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7937257/361684.  How to print a date in a certain format:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14638191/361684.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572561/javascript-set-date-10-days-in-the-future-in-this-format-dd-mm-yyyy-e-g-21-0

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3818198/361684.  It gives you exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Date methods are smart enough to support this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10 /*days*/);
```

The date in this example will be 10 days ahead current date.

Answer (score 4):

This will help

```
Date.prototype.addDays=function(d) {
   return new Date(this.getTime() + d*86400000); // milliseconds
};
console.log(new Date().addDays(5);
```

or

```
Date.prototype.addDays=function(d) {
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + d*86400000);
   return this;
};
var time=new Date();
time.addDays(5);
console.log(time);
```